# Why can't Chef node find a private key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Im trying to install chef on my AWS ec2 instances. Im using one ec2 as a workstation, another as a node and hosted chef as the chef server.

On the workstation, Im able to create a simple project (LAMP stack) and upload it to the chef server.
When I run knife bootstrap on the workstation with the key pair for the nodes ec2 instance, it successfully converges.

```
Chef Client finished, 1/1 resources updated in 01 minutes 23 seconds
```

When I go to the chef node however and run chef-client, I get the following error:

```
Private Key Not Found:
----------------------
Your private key could not be loaded. If the key file exists, ensure that it is
readable by chef-client.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
validation_key "/etc/chef/validation.pem"

System Info:
------------
chef_version=14.12.9
ruby=ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2019-05-17T21:35:04+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-05-17T21:35:04+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 00 seconds
[2019-05-17T21:35:04+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ubuntu/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-05-17T21:35:04+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-05-17T21:35:04+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
```

On the workstation, I run knife list and I can see my node and validator listed. In hosted chef I can't see the chef node listed under nodes.

Please can you help me understand the error and how to fix it?
I was under the impression that bootstrap takes care of the nodes certificates so Im surprised the node can't load the private key.

Thank you

Comment: check the permissions for your key file, should be readable by the current process.

Comment: the file permission is -rw-r--r-- though Im trying to figure out what that means? Im referring to the key file on the workstation

Comment: Here is an explanation of what it means https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions. Meanwhile try to do ```chmod 400 /etc/chef/validation.pem```.  Certificates should be readable only by the owner.

Comment: So after doing that the validation.pem file on the node now has -r--------  1 root root 1679 May 17 22:12 validation.pem. running chef-client still gives the same error though. I changed client.pem to 400 too but with no affect.